# I need to be able to execute a function call by passing the full function call statement as a parameter - java

Tags: java, function

lets say I have below

```
class abc{
    void doSomething(String abc){
        //does Something
    }
}
```

- I need to be able to create a function that I can pass the full call
  as parameter.

  functionCall(doSomething(abc)){}
- please advice if this is possible. similar to what happens in an if
  statement.

Comment: Take a look at [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)

Comment: It already works like an **`if`** `doSomething` does not return a `boolean`. Just like `if (doSomething(abc))` is not legal, `functionCall(doSomething(abc))` is not legal. The method is `void`. This seems like an XY-problem, what are you trying to do with this functional parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function with one parameter and no return type as [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

```java
static void functionCall(Consumer<String> function, String argument) {
    function.accept(argument); // Call the method with the argument.
}
...
    Abc object = new Abc();
    Consumer<String> function = object::doSomething; // Get function variable.
    functionCall(function, "foobar");
```

---

As your method is an instance method, you need to get the method reference through an instance of the class. This is what I have `object` for. This syntax works on Java 11.0.6.

Comment: Suggest having an inner interface declared in the class that needs this function passed in, then accept the interface in the class's constructor. (If there's only one method in the interface, you can pass a lambda in instead of implementing an entire interface.)

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that takes a Consumer functional interface as argument

```
public static void functionCall(Consumer<String> consumer, String value) {
    consumer.accept(value);
}
```

Then use it like below, this solution is for Java 8. For newer versions you can do this in a cleaner way. See answer from @akuzminykh

```
Abc abc = new Abc();
functionalCall(s -> abc.doSomething(s), "Hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the method `doSomething` in an abstract class (Abc) and then create a anonymous class an call the method that you want ie:

```
public class TemplateExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TemplateExample instance = new TemplateExample();
        PrintSomething pa = instance.new PrintSomething() {
            @Override
            void print() {
                System.out.println("PrintSomething pa");
            }
        };

        PrintSomething pb = instance.new PrintSomething() {
            @Override
            void print() {
                System.out.println("PrintSomething pb");
            }
        };

        pa.print();
        pb.print();

    }

    abstract class PrintSomething {
        abstract void print();
    }  
}
```